# Loop through all tables in database to fetch 2 rows per table

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

I have a database wherein there are multiple owners and some tables are empty.

Currently I want to sequentially execute the same fetch query against all non-empty tables of a specific owner.

I wrote the PL/SQL below, but got this error "ORA-06550: line 8, column 41: PLS-00497: cannot mix between single row and multi-row (BULK) in INTO list 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s".

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR details IS 
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM all_tables 
    WHERE owner = 'emp' AND num_rows > 0;
  myvar all_tables.table_name%TYPE;
  rows_num NATURAL := 2;
  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    OPEN details;
    LOOP
        FETCH details BULK COLLECT INTO myvar LIMIT rows_num;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE details;
END;
```

How can I fix this?

**edit**: New code with SELECT included:

```
BEGIN
  OPEN details;
  LOOP
    FETCH details INTO my_var;
    EXIT WHEN myvar%NOTFOUND;
    sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM ' || my_var|| ' WHERE ROWNUM <= :rows_num';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_stmt);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE table_cur;
END;
```

No more errors now but I couldn't see anything in the Dbms output.

Comment: This code will not do what you want, because you do not perform any `select` query for a given table

Comment: @astentx I've updated it to include select, could you check for me please? Thanks

Comment: Do you specifically need to fetch the rows into an array? If you don't, then most of your complexity could be done away with by using a basic cursor loop with no need to define the cursor nor the types at the top. This has the added advantage of not holding the array in memory. I once made a utility that used arrays like yours, and it worked in dozens of databases, but one day I found a database with so many tables that I ran out of memory just because of the size of the array. So, if the tables can be looped through without having an array, all the better.

Comment: Because you do not receive query result into anything. But to fetch a result set you have to provide some PL/SQL variable with the structure of the result set. In short: it's very hard to print query results dynamically with PL/SQL

Answer (score 1):

As P3CONSULTING said - declare TYPE of TABLE of CURSOR%ROWTYPE and then a variable that has type that newly declared TABLE OF type. Also please do not forget to add condition in loop to avoid infinite loop. Please try this code:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR details IS 
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM all_tables 
    WHERE owner = 'emp' AND num_rows > 0;
  type t_var is table of details%rowtype;
  myvar t_var;
  rows NATURAL := 2;
BEGIN
    OPEN details;
    LOOP
        FETCH details BULK COLLECT INTO myvar LIMIT rows;
        EXIT WHEN myvar.count = 0;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE details;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable into which you "BULK COLLECT" must be a "TABLE OF..." not a single ROWTYPE.

Answer (score 0):

Combining everything you need the below.Which satisfies all your requirements.The Sql fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lywnrlxz)

```
      DECLARE
      CURSOR details IS
        SELECT a.table_name, a.owner
          FROM all_tables a
         WHERE a.owner = user
           AND a.num_rows > 0;
      type t_var is table of details%rowtype;
      myvar   t_var;
      rows1   NATURAL := 2;
      v_plsql varchar2(32767);
      i       number := 0;
    BEGIN
      OPEN details;
      LOOP
        dbms_output.enable;
        FETCH details BULK COLLECT
          INTO myvar;
        if NOT myvar.EXISTS(1) THEN
          EXIT;
        end if;
        for i in myvar.first .. myvar.last loop
          if NOT myvar.EXISTS(i) THEN
            EXIT;
          end if;
          v_plsql := 'DECLARE ' || ' type rec_row is table of ' || myvar(i)
                    .table_name || '%rowtype; ' || 'l_row rec_row;' || 'BEGIN ' ||
                     '  SELECT * ' || ' BULK COLLECT   INTO l_row ' ||
                     '    FROM ' || myvar(i).table_name || '    where rownum<=' ||
                     rows1 || ';' ||
                     ' if l_row.EXISTS(1) then dbms_output.put_line(''' || i ||
                     ' table and 1 row' || '''' || '); dbms_output.put_line(''';
          for rec in (select a.*,
                             (select max(column_id)
                                from all_tab_cols a
                               where table_name = myvar(i).table_name) max_column
                        from all_tab_cols a
                       where table_name = myvar(i).table_name
                       order by column_id) loop
            v_plsql := v_plsql || rec.column_name;
            if rec.column_id <> rec.max_column then
              v_plsql := v_plsql || ',';
            end if;
          end loop;
          v_plsql := v_plsql || '''); dbms_output.put_line(';
          for rec in (select a.*,
                             (select max(column_id)
                                from all_tab_cols a
                               where table_name = myvar(i).table_name) max_column
                        from all_tab_cols a
                       where table_name = myvar(i).table_name
                       order by column_id) loop
            v_plsql := v_plsql || ' l_row(1).' || rec.column_name;
            if rec.column_id <> rec.max_column then
              v_plsql := v_plsql || '||'',''||';
            end if;
          end loop;
          v_plsql := v_plsql || '); end if;';
        
          v_plsql := v_plsql ||
                     'if l_row.EXISTS(2) then dbms_output.put_line(''' || i ||
                     ' table and 2 row' || '''' || '); dbms_output.put_line(''';
        
          for rec in (select a.*,
                             (select max(column_id)
                                from all_tab_cols a
                               where table_name = myvar(i).table_name) max_column
                        from all_tab_cols a
                       where table_name = myvar(i).table_name
                       order by column_id) loop
            v_plsql := v_plsql || rec.column_name || '';
            if rec.column_id <> rec.max_column then
              v_plsql := v_plsql || ',';
            end if;
          end loop;
          v_plsql := v_plsql || '''); dbms_output.put_line(';
        
          for rec in (select a.*,
                             (select max(column_id)
                                from all_tab_cols a
                               where table_name = myvar(i).table_name) max_column
                        from all_tab_cols a
                       where table_name = myvar(i).table_name
                       order by column_id) loop
            v_plsql := v_plsql || ' l_row(2).' || rec.column_name;
            if rec.column_id <> rec.max_column then
              v_plsql := v_plsql || '||'',''||';
            end if;
          
          end loop;
          v_plsql := v_plsql || '); end if;';
        
          v_plsql := v_plsql || ' end;';
          --dbms_output.put_line(v_plsql);
          execute immediate v_plsql;
        end loop;
        exit;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE details;
    END;
    /
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need an output to be of specific format, then you may use `dbms_xmlgen` to execute dynamic SQL and serialize result into XML document.

Setup:

> ```
> create table t0
> as
> select *
> from user_tables
> where 1=0
> ```
>
> ```
> create table t1
> as
> select level as id
> from dual
> connect by level < 5
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```
>
> ```
> create table t2
> as
> select *
> from all_objects
> where rownum = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```
>
> ```
> create table t3
> as
> select *
> from all_source
> where rownum < 5
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

The query:

```
select * from (
select
  owner, table_name
  , dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
    replace(replace (
      'select * from "schema"."table" where rownum < 3'
      , 'schema', owner)
      , 'table', table_name
    )
  ) as res
from all_tables
where owner = user
)
where res is not null
```

| OWNER | TABLE_NAME | RES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FIDDLE_AIMBWFSLKTLDLGCECWIY | T1 | <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROWSET> <ROW> <ID>1</ID> </ROW> <ROW> <ID>2</ID> </ROW> </ROWSET> |
| FIDDLE_AIMBWFSLKTLDLGCECWIY | T2 | <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROWSET> <ROW> <OWNER>SYS</OWNER> <OBJECT_NAME>ORA$BASE</OBJECT_NAME> <OBJECT_ID>134</OBJECT_ID> <OBJECT_TYPE>EDITION</OBJECT_TYPE> <CREATED>17-AUG-21</CREATED> <LAST_DDL_TIME>17-AUG-21</LAST_DDL_TIME> <TIMESTAMP>2021-08-17:23:05:16</TIMESTAMP> <STATUS>VALID</STATUS> <TEMPORARY>N</TEMPORARY> <GENERATED>N</GENERATED> <SECONDARY>N</SECONDARY> <NAMESPACE>64</NAMESPACE> <SHARING>NONE</SHARING> <ORACLE_MAINTAINED>Y</ORACLE_MAINTAINED> <APPLICATION>N</APPLICATION> <DUPLICATED>N</DUPLICATED> <SHARDED>N</SHARDED> <IMPORTED_OBJECT>N</IMPORTED_OBJECT> </ROW> </ROWSET> |
| FIDDLE_AIMBWFSLKTLDLGCECWIY | T3 | <?xml version="1.0"?> <ROWSET> <ROW> <OWNER>SYS</OWNER> <NAME>STANDARD</NAME> <TYPE>PACKAGE</TYPE> <LINE>1</LINE> <TEXT>package STANDARD AUTHID CURRENT_USER is -- careful on this line; SED edit occurs! </TEXT> <ORIGIN_CON_ID>1</ORIGIN_CON_ID> </ROW> <ROW> <OWNER>SYS</OWNER> <NAME>STANDARD</NAME> <TYPE>PACKAGE</TYPE> <LINE>2</LINE> <TEXT> </TEXT> <ORIGIN_CON_ID>1</ORIGIN_CON_ID> </ROW> </ROWSET> |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_KztKp-G)